# Android - Best way to constantly receive info from server?

Tags: java, android, tcp

I have an Android client that needs to request information from my server. The information on my server is updated randomly and can be updated every second or minute. Communication is done via raw TCP/IP. My current method of is having the Android client request the info every few seconds on a loop. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Would having the client request it every second kill battery? It's something like this:

1. Open connection to server
2. Send request message
3. Server responds
4. Client closes connection
5. Repeat after 5 seconds

Comment: Depends on a protocol you are going to use.

Comment: This is exactly why they invented GCM

Comment: If no Internet connection (internal use only), have you tried SignalR?

Comment: @BNK - Internet is required.

Answer (score -2):

Why doesn't your server sends a notification when this event happens? I mean using [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging). Follow the guide there, it will help you.

Comment: I'd like to stick to raw TCP/IP if possible for simplicity.

Comment: @John: Why raw TCP/IP?

Comment: Just for simplicity. If it can't be done simply on TCP/IP I'll look into GCM.

Comment: I think GCM is a very simple approach. The messages are light too. It's what everyday apps do. For example, a chat app sends a push notification each time a new message is sent. If the content is large, you can use the push message to notify (maybe with a url) and then the client requests something to the server.

Comment: @bryant1410 hi bryant, do you know how to overcome delays on gcm ? Thanks

Comment: I think using GCM is a very simple approach. The messages are light in size too. Everyday apps use it. For example a chat app could send a push message every time a message is sent to the user. If you want to send something large, you could notify the client (maybe with a url?) so it requests the content to the server

Comment: Even short messages have delays

Comment: @MelvinMauricio delays? It's pretty fast. Using the sender in the page http://stackoverflow.com/a/22169411/1165181 and an emulator drives the messages almost instantly

Comment: yeah sometimes fast.. and sometimes slow.. i got a delay of notification for about 20 minutes...

Comment: @MelvinMauricio but which use are we talking about? Chat applications use it and it's blazing fast.

Comment: @MelvinMauricio I have never had such delay. Are you sure you had internet connection?

Comment: yes im sure i had an internet connection. There are many threads about gcm being delayed on notifications.

Comment: ok. you could use another push messaging server, or host your own maybe