# How can I send a complex structured JSON via Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I'm starting with the new Google service for the notifications, Firebase Cloud Messaging. I am able to send notifications from my Firebase User Console to my Android device for testing.

The problem I'm struggling with is that I can't send a complex structured data via Console > Compose Message. For example `"prop3": {"inner": 42, "inner2": "test data", {"go": "deeper"}}` becomes `"prop3": "{\"inner\": 42, \"inner2\": \"test data\", {\"go\": \"deeper\"}}"`. I expect it to be a JSON tree with nested nodes, but what I get is a plain string.

[image: problem demo]

Is there any way to send a notification with nested properties using the Firebase console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this on console. Hit FCM server with custom request.

You can refer this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30778643/4620609

Comment: I got your point. Just want to add to your answer that the referenced example is for GCM and for FCM the target URL should be https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send