# How to test FCM push notifications in Android

Tags: android, firebase, junit, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing a [FCM notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) integration & it's working fine. To test component is there a way to mock RemoteMessage object?

By mocking I mean to perform Junit test case.
Any suggestion !

Comment: Printout token and use Firebase console to push notification on the token.

Comment: That is in working state. I'm worrying about to perform test cases. Any idea !!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168819/android-test-push-notification-online-google-cloud-messaging or https://pushtry.com/

Comment: @SivakumarS I'm looking for Junit testing. Update in question info.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your `FirebaseMessagingService` subclass and set breakpoint on the `onMessageReceived` method. Send a normal push notification like you normally do. Inspect `remoteMessage` object while standing on breakpoint. One of the properties of this object would be `Bundle`. Now, you just need to manually create a `Bundle` that looks the same and then create `RemoteMessage` with that bundle, e.g.:

```
val bundle = Bundle().apply {
    // System fields
    putString("google.delivered_priority", "high")
    putLong("google.sent_time", Date().time)
    putLong("google.ttl", 2419200)
    putString("google.original_priority", "high")
    putString("google.message_id", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    putString("from", <your fcm project_number, from google-services.json>)

    // Custom fields
    putString("type", "my-type")
    putString("message", "Me message")
    ...
}
val remoteMessage = RemoteMessage(bundle)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to mock a `RemoteMessage` object used in FCM. AFAIK, there isn't even a way to test the `onMessageReceived()` method without using the actual service.

What is only valid to do is to test your `sendNotification()` (or whatever you named your method) that hopefully accepts a Hashmap that may come from the `RemoteMessage` object (this is of course if you're only using a *data message payload*.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't, and there are no signs of supporting it in the near future.

**What you can do:** what we did, was to build an API command in your server, that would send you a test push. It would be tedious to support, but that's as good as it gets.

Even worse: suppose that the testing is done to guarantee reliability. What if it fails? You request a new token but FCM will give you the same one, probably... but it does not work! If you invalidate and request a token - will it help? Not sure.

Your options are limited indeed.